# Initialize object from unknown derived class of known base class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

So, I'm making a library for a little D2D Engine; but that's not the point, the thing is, I have this class which will be the base class the user's class will inherit. My main idea would be something like this:

```cpp
struct BaseEngine {
    // I have two pure virtual functions so the user has to define them.
    virtual bool onLoad() = 0;
    virtual bool onFrame() = 0;
};
```

Now, if it all were to be in the same project, I could do something like this right after that:

```cpp
struct Derived : public BaseEngine {
    bool onLoad() override;
    bool onFrame() override;
};

const std::unique_ptr<BaseEngine> app = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

But my idea is, in fact, to not hold the derived class in my header files, and build the library without any possible definition of a derived class, thus, the user can just name it whatever they want in their project.

Of course it won't let me compile it, because I can't construct `BaseEngine` because it has pure virtual functions.

Then I though of somehow using templates to maybe solve this issue? Now I'm not very familiar with templates, but my idea was to make something like:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<BaseEngine> app;
template<class T : public BaseEngine>
void instantiator() {
    app = std::make_unique<T>();
}
```

Knowing that `T` holds an implementation for `onLoad()` and `onFrame()`.
But of course, when I need a feature such as templates of explicitly derived classes, no feature exists (not that I know of, at least).

My main question being: **is there a way for me to initialize an object from an "unknown" derived class of my known base class?**

**Edit: forgot to mention that the main function (WinMain in this case) will be on the engine side, as it takes care of window class registration and all those nasty messages.**

Comment: I'm confused how this is supposed to be used. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to have the user call some sort of initialization function and provide the pointer to the derived class there?

Comment: Two comments here: Firstly, it's unclear why code that doesn't know about derived classes needs to create instances. Secondly, check whether the so-called "Factory Pattern" could be a solution.

Comment: As it stands, just remove `: public BaseEngine` from your pseudocode and it will work as you intend. C++ templates are not Java/C# generics, they will accept any type that leads to valid code by default.

Comment: @UnholySheep basically because the library will be the one owning the WinMain, to set everything up (window class creation, registration, etc.), so Windows calls WinMain on the engine side of things which then sort of "hooks" to the derived class. This "design idea" is highly inspired on how Minecraft Bukkit initializes its plugins (though it simply uses reflection to find the class you provide the name as a String in Java).

Answer (score 0):

#### Static polymorphism: the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)

You may want to consider using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP):

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> struct BaseEngine {
  bool onLoad() const { return static_cast<T const *>(this)->onLoad(); }
  bool onFrame() { return static_cast<T *>(this)->onLoad(); }
};

// API exposed to library users.
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BaseEngine<T>, T>::value>>
auto createEngine() {
  return std::make_unique<T>();
}

template <typename T> bool foo(const BaseEngine<T> &engine) {
  return engine.onLoad();
}

// Stub for your own testing etc.
struct StubEngine : BaseEngine<StubEngine> {
  bool onLoad() const {
    std::cout << "stub onLoad()\n";
    return true;
  }
  bool onFrame() {
    std::cout << "stub onFrame()\n";
    return false;
  }
};

struct BadEngine {};

int main() {
  auto engine = createEngine<StubEngine>();
  // auto bad_engine = createEngine<BadEngine>();
  // error: no matching function for call to 'createEngine'

  const bool f = foo(*engine);      // stub onLoad()
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << f; // true

  return 0;
}
```

By implementing static polymorphism using templates, you can work within you lib with a type template parameter `T` in the context of `BaseEngine` without having to know what `T` is (as it will be up to the library user to implement particular concrete "statically derived" classes, i.e., specific `T`'s); possibly placing, however, restrictions on `T` using type traits and SFINAE.

Comment: Hmm, this is something I would consider a solution because of the type traits, but one key point I left unmentioned is that main (WinMain in this case) will be in the engine side, as it takes care of the whole window class registration, creation and the whole message queue processing. And that's one of the main reasons I'm wanting to instantiate the unknown derived class from the engine side.
By the look of things, I'll probably end up either providing a small implementation of the derived class or make `onLoad()` and `onFrame()` non-pure virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd like to compile your code as a shared library, that you can link to in another project that will become the main executable. Unfortunately, there can be issues sharing class types between libraries and executables due to differences in how they might be compiled--I wouldn't recommend going down that route.

If you can compile it all at once, though (i.e. the user has access to uncompiled source and header files) you won't have to deal with that. Just provide a function that takes an instance of `BaseEngine`.

```cpp
// BaseEngine.h
class BaseEngine { /* ... */ }
void startGame(std::unique_ptr<BaseEngine> engine) { /* ... */ }

// main.cpp (user edits this file)
#include "BaseEngine.h"

class DerivedEngine : public BaseEngine {
   // override methods here
}

int main() {
   return startGame(std::make_unique<DerivedEngine>());
}
```

Comment: Well, it'll be provided as a static library, but I'll probably have to create a derived class somewhere, which is what I'm trying to avoid. But one of the other key points (which I left unmentioned) is that WinMain will be on the engine side of things, as it will take care of window registration from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to this would be to have a function in your engine that takes a caller-created BaseEngine derived  object as an argument.

```
// Engine side function
bool InitializeEngine(BaseEngine * pEngine);
```

An alternative answer (depending on how the user-supplied code is bundled) would be to have an exported function with a set name and have that function return a created BaseEngine derived object.

```
// User side code
BaseEngine * CreateEngine();
```

And then use dlopen/dlsym (or LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress on windows) to obtain the function pointer for CreateEngine. In either case it is the user's code where the object type is known that is responsible for creating the object.